# Управление через БД обьектами на сайте

Tags: php, javascript, html, база-данных, json

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такая страничка ,сразу говорю с php my admin  не работал и с json тоже по этому и спрашиваю . На странице нужно управлять цветом заливки одного из насосов . На подобие : в базе данных в таблицу забил 1 - кружок закрасился зеленым , забил 2 - синим ,3 - красный . Информации в нете пересмотрел кучу но ничего толкового . Помогите пожалуйста ,а то неделю сижу над этим (

Comment: Если вы хотите. чтобы у вас на открытой странице периодически самостоятельно менялся цвет, то вам либо опрашивать сервер через ajax с необходимой периодичностью, либо наоборот ждать уведомлений от сервера через сокеты. 
Аякс должен спросит сервер, сервер посмотрит что там в БД, вернет значение. js в свою очередь добавить css-класс  кружочку с нужным цветом заливки.

Comment: В том то и дело что на теории я сам понимаю как это должно происходить но на практике полная фигня получается.

Comment: Так покажите что вы делаете? За вас здесь никто весь код не напишет.